# How can I (as a user) check if AP isolation is enabled for a Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wifi, access-point, mirroring, isolated-network

I suspect AP isolation is enabled on the Wi-Fi network at my workplace as I can't cast my phone screen to another device that supports Miracast.

Casting works just fine on my home network with the same devices connected to my home Wi-Fi.

How can I, as a user with no access to the router configuration know whether or not AP isolation is enabled for any Wi-Fi network? Is it even possible?

Comment: How about asking the network administrators at your workplace?

Comment: @JennyD it's more of a generic question and not really about a specific wireless network